# Substitutions in Makefile

Tags: makefile

```
ifeq ($(SYSTEM),WINDOWS)
# need to change something here :
RM = @(if exist "$(subst /,\,$(DIRECTORY))" rmdir /s /q $(subst/,\,$(DIRECTORY))))
else
RM := @rm -rf
endif

clean_1 :
    $(RM) SOME/PATH/

clean_2 :
    $(RM) SOME/PATH/
```

How to make a substitution path "SOME/PATH/" to "DIRECTORY"?
Is this possible without changing the structure of the code?

P.S. I can not use *rmdir* without checking for the file, as it generates an error.

UPDATE. I did so:

```
ifeq ($(SYSTEM),WINDOWS)
RM = @(if exist "$(subst /,\,$1)" rmdir /s /q $(subst/,\,$1)))
else
RM = @rm -rf $1
endif

clean_% :
    $(call RM, SOME/PATH/)
```

It really works. Thanks to Mark Galeck.

Is there a way to do this by replacing *RM* variable, without changing *clean*-target commands?

Comment: Is there some reason you *want* to do it that way?

Comment: No special reason. But I wonder, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, I added to my answer.  Yes, you want to list the directories with each clean target - it was dumb of me to not realize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make `RM` a function (consult the manual for how to do that).

You would then have

```
clean_%:
    $(call RM, SOME/PATH/)
```

Yes you can also do this without changing the target names, just replace `$(RM)` with the function call, in your original rules.

Actually, I think the best way to handle the situation which you seem to have, where one filesystem is accessed from two OS, would be to introduce a variable for separator

```
/ := $(if $(filter WINDOWS, $(SYSTEM)),\,/)
```

Now, you can just always use `SOME$/PATH` and you don't have to change anything else - only put `$` in front of `/` where you need to make paths available to Windows as well